# Error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, runtime-error

I am creating a for loop that generates graphs. The problem that I have is when I put my graph generating script into a for loop in breaks giving me the error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined for the datapoint array. The code works outside of a for loop though.

```
datapoint=[[1],[1]]
LabelList=[]
Classyaverage=0
colorOption=""
ChartName = 'Chart0'
NumOfCharts = 2
ChartNum = 1
TotalChartNum = 2
ListNum = 0
counter = 0
public graphComponent: GraphComponent= new GraphComponent();
constructor(private HttpModule : Http) { } // end of constructor

public graphGenerator(){
```

Breaks Like this

```
this.ListNum = 9

for(this.counter = 1; this.counter <= this.NumOfCharts; this.counter++){

  var i=0
  this.LabelList=[]
  this.ChartNum = this.counter
  this.ChartName = this.ChartName.slice(0,-1)
  this.ChartName = this.ChartName + this.counter
  console.log(this.ChartName)
  while(i< this.ListNum){
      i++
      this.LabelList.push('')
  }

  this.datapoint[this.ChartNum].push(this.Classyaverage)
  if(Object.keys(this.datapoint[this.ChartNum]).length > this.ListNum){
      this.datapoint[this.ChartNum].shift()
  }

  this.graphComponent.setGraph(this.datapoint, this.LabelList, this.ChartName, this.ChartNum)

}
```

Works Like This

```
var i=0
this.LabelList=[]
this.ChartNum = 1
this.ChartName = 'ChartA'
this.ListNum = 19
while(i< this.ListNum){
    i++
    this.LabelList.push('')
}

this.datapoint[this.ChartNum].push(this.Classyaverage)
if(Object.keys(this.datapoint[this.ChartNum]).length > this.ListNum){
  this.datapoint[this.ChartNum].shift()
}

this.graphComponent.setGraph(this.datapoint, this.LabelList, this.ChartName, this.ChartNum)

setTimeout(() => { this.graphGenerator(); }, 500);

}
```

Comment: is there a specific reason you're assigning to a list within a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push values to an array, like `this.datapoint.push()`, but you cannot push to `this.datapoint[someNumber]` if that call doesn't return an array or is undefined. Then what you end up calling is `undefined.push()` which doesn't work.

I don't quite understand why we're pushing the value to an inner array in the first place, then performing a shift on the array. Why not do something more direct? In addition, since we're in a for loop it's probably better to define new variables instead of changing the class variables. Something like this:

```
  public graphGenerator() {
    for (let counter = 1; counter <= this.NumOfCharts; counter++) {

      const labelList = Array.from({length: this.ListNum}, _ => '');
      const chartName = this.ChartName.slice(0, -1) + counter;
      const datapoint = [this.Classyaverage]

      this.graphComponent.setGraph(datapoint, labelList, chartName, counter);

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When it's out of the for loop ChartNum is equal to 1, well an item in datapoint exists at that index (the second entry in datapoint, it starts at 0), and so you can push to it.

When you put it into the for loop ChartNum is equal to the counter, which changes at each iteration. The counter starts at 1.

An item only exists at index 0 ([1]) and index 1 ([1]) in datapoint ([[1],[1]]), as soon as ChartNum is 2 it's going to fail, as nothing is at that index.

You should do this.datapoint[this.ChartNum - 1]

That should fix your issue.

Comment: That helped so much! I created a while loops that adds in another array point for each chart I make! Thanks!